# Which direction before dawn to look for Comet Lovejoy (C/2011 W3)?

Tags: astronomy, comets

Various websites today are reporting with photos and videos of [Comet Lovejoy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C/2011_W3_%28Lovejoy%29). However, I can't seem to find a definition of which direction to look for it tomorrow morning. I'm in [Christchurch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christchurch), [New Zealand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Zealand) (roughly 43°S 173°E).

Answer (score 2):

According to Starry Night, Comet Lovejoy will rise this morning in the Southeast around 4 a.m. in Christchurch. Not a chance of seeing it here in Canada, alas!

Answer (score 1):

Very near where the sun will rise, i.e. east.  Lovejoy is still close to the sun.
Good luck!!

Comment: Yeah that's roughly what my guess was after looking at online photos of it taken this morning and the relative sky brightness around.  It's meant to be only partly cloudy tomorrow, so early start ahead for me! ;) Thanks!